# Absolute Positioned Element Not Staying in Relative Parent

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm building a multi-step form and then animating the steps. I've grouped the different questions into separate `fieldsets`, then animate those `fieldsteps`. The parent wrapper has `position:relative` applied.

When you click "previous", you can see the footer falls behind the `fieldset` that now has `position:absolute`. How do I stop this? I can't have an explicit height set on the parent, as it'll change from one step to the next.

https://codepen.io/JustHam/pen/yLejWVZ

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed inside your click listener for the Next button you are setting the position of `current_fs` to absolute, but in the Previous button's click listener, you aren't changing the position back to relative.

I altered your `complete` function inside the Previous button's click listener, changing the position of `previous_fs` back to relative and it seems to be working:

```js
      complete: function () {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
        previous_fs.css({position: 'relative'})
      },
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you for taking the time to look through that.